# Initialize expensive element with ng-if then show/hide with ng-show/hide

Tags: angularjs

I have an element whose generation is expensive. As such, I do not include it on initial page load using:

```
<div id='myExpensiveElement' ng-if='showElement'>
```

If the user clicks a particular button:

```
<button ng-click='showElement = !showElement'>
```

the expensive element is generated and inserted into the DOM. The user may choose to hide that element by clicking the button again. However, this causes the element to be removed from the DOM, requiring it to be generated again.

Is there a way to combine ng-show/hide with ng-if such that if the element has been generated once, switch to use ng-show/hide instead of ng-if?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this without a custom directive would be to use another variable to track the initialization...

```
<button ng-click='showElement = !showElement; elementInitialized = true'></button>
<div id='myExpensiveElement' ng-if='elementInitialized' ng-show='showElement'> 
...
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/26hQM/)