# ng-if calling an ng-show?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I have an `ng-if` and if it evaluates to TRUE, I want it to call an `ng-show="someMethod()"`

What would you say is the best way to do this?

Should I call my `ng-if` then use an `ng-init="someMethod()"` and then in someMethod() somehow apply a mock of `ng-show`?

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,item) in foodOptions" ng-class={hidden : item.type != currentSection.type}" >
```

I then want to call an ng-if to call a specific condition like `ng-if="item.type === 'pizza'"` - this should then call an ng-show="someMethod()" which will filter available dropdowns on the page etc.

Comment: Can you post your HTML also?

Comment: not clear what problem is just adding both attributes. When `ng-if` evaluates false...element won't even exist

Comment: @charlietfl -- I ONLY want it to call the ng-show IF the ng-if condition is met. If the ng-if condition is not met, then skip the ng-show. Hope that clarifies it!

Comment: don't think you understand what `ng-if` does. It will not produce an element if the condition is false

Comment: @charlietfl That's what I was thinking. I guess I should have said something like I want the ng-show to ONLY occur if some condition is true. I don't want the ng-show running each time that div is generated, just on a specific condition to apply the ng-show. Is this better handled from the controller?

Comment: What's wrong with nesting your ng-show in your ng-if?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-if` does not render that element if condition evaluates to false

However you can use multiple conditions in one expression:

```
ng-show="item.type == 'pizza' && someMethod()"
```

It is generally better not to put function calls in such conditionals though

Comment: That's closer to what I want, but I want it to call the ng-show ONLY if that first condition is met. I guess I could use an ng-class="{hidden : someMethod()}" possibly to just hide the element if the conditions are true.

Comment: `someMethod()` here will be called only for pizzas. It's called "short-circuit evaluation". Why would you want to render dropdowns and not show them? Why not just not render them?

Comment: At least, it should short-circuit here

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - I need to render it because I'll need to show it based on another condition within the someMethod() function. It'll have an if/else if/else structure that returns true/false based on several conditions within.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-show` evaluates an expression already - just put your expression into the `ng-show ="myexpression || myfunction()"`.

If your element or expression is not initialized then you should use ng-if to make sure this element only exists once the expression is read. Have a look at this:[Initialize expensive element with ng-if then show/hide with ng-show/hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109154/initialize-expensive-element-with-ng-if-then-show-hide-with-ng-show-hide).

`<button ng-click='showElement = !showElement; elementInitialized = true'></button>
<div id='myExpensiveElement' ng-if='elementInitialized' ng-show='showElement'> 
...
</div>`

As you see - the ng-show can directly follow the ng-if, and if false then ng-show doesn't happen until it is initialialized.

Comment: But will the element still exist if the ng-if is false? I want it to still show, but just not call the ng-show.

Comment: The point in the code example is to exclude the element until it has been initialized, and then use ng-show to show or not show it.  This is the standard method of using ng-if to prevent non-initialized elements to appear.  If you want the element to always appear then don't use ng-if, just put the expression into ng-show